# Makefile does not work on mac os x Mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, makefile

I have a project, which uses opencv library. Today I have upgraded my Mac OS X Lion to Mavericks and now I am wondering why it does not compile anymore because of the following error:

```
c++ -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0    -c -o Hello.o Hello.cpp
Hello.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv/cv.h' file not found
#include "opencv/cv.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Hello.o] Error 1
```

Here's the code of Hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 

OBJS =      Hello.o

LIBS =  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_gpu


INCPATH = -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include
LIBPATH = -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib

TARGET =    Hello

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    g++ $(INCPATH) $(LIBPATH) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) 


all:    $(TARGET)


clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I have to say that I can compile my project using terminal by typing:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` Hello.cpp -o Hello
```

and to be sure, this is what I get by running `pkg-config --cflags opencv` on terminal:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include/opencv
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters but you have an unwanted trailing `/` here: `INCPATH = -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include/` - this should really be `INCPATH = -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include`.

Comment: Also can you paste a transcript of what you get in Terminal after typing `make`, right up the fatal error message?

Comment: @PaulR, thanks for your comment. No it does not. I already modified that in the question

Comment: OK - let's see the transcript then...

Comment: You can see it in the question, I just added it

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow you. By typing make in terminal, I get what I have copied above (one line was missing which is added now).Is that what you  mean?

Comment: Yes - that was the important part - I can now see that your makefile is broken.

Comment: Ok, any solution? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this makefile ever worked, unless somehow the new version of MacOSX has moved those headers out of the standard location into a different location.

You are using the default built-in rules, as Paul R says, but you are not using the default make variables that go with those rules.  I would write my makefile like this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include

OBJS =      Hello.o

LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib
LDLIBS =  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video \
          -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect \
          -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_gpu

TARGET =    Hello

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
         $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1):

You makefile does not have an explicit rule for building Hello.o so it is using a default rule. There are various ways to handle this but I would just change it to:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 

SRCS =      Hello.cpp

LIBS =  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_gpu

INCPATH = -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/include
LIBPATH = -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib

TARGET =    Hello

$(TARGET):  $(SRCS)
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $(LIBPATH) -o $(TARGET) $(SRCS) $(LIBS) 

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: This is not a good answer.  It will work OK for a single source file (which should be `Hello.cpp` not `Hello.c`) but it's not right if you have >1 source file.

Comment: @MadScientist: actually it works OK for multiple source files (try it!), but admittedly it becomes unwieldy if you have more than a few source files. I was going for the minimal number of changes to the OP's makefile, but of course your answer is more scalable in the long run.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work :-).  I said it's "not right": this makefile is not much better than a shell script.  The only real advantage it has is over a simple script containing the link line that if you change NO source files it won't relink (but how often do you run make without changing anything?)  But if you change ANY source file it will recompile ALL source files, so it's not a good use of make.

Answer (score 0):

Dear i got the same error, please have a look here:

[C++ linking error after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 / Xcode 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637164/c-linking-error-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-xcode-5-0-1)

very quick solution:  add -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linking command.