# C++ linking error after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 / Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: c++, linker, clang++, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 / Xcode 5.0.1, command lines to create a shared library (.dylib) failed with several undefined symbols.

```
clang++ -dynamiclib -install_name test.dylib *.o -o test.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::allocator<char>::allocator()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::allocator<char>::~allocator()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in test.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer is there: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34692/mathlink-linking-error-after-os-x-10-9-mavericks-upgrade

> There are two implementations of the standard C++ library available on OS X: libstdc++ and libc++. They are not binary compatible and libMLi3 requires libstdc++.
>
> On 10.8 and earlier libstdc++ is chosen by default, on 10.9 libc++ is chosen by default. To ensure compatibility with libMLi3, we need to choose libstdc++ manually.
>
> To do this, add -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linking command.

Related post: [Compiling with Clang using Libc++ undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016730/compiling-with-clang-using-libc-undefined-references)

---

**Edit**: After some investigations it seems there is a link between the `-mmacosx-version-min` and the choice of the default `libstd`. If min version < 10.9, then the default `libstd` is equal to `libstdc++`, else to `libc++`. The long term solution is clearly to use `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: do you know how to make "-stdlib=libc++"  the default permanently?

Comment: excuse me, but have you got the answer of how to "add -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linking command" ? @Ajay

Comment: It's a setup of your building tool.

Comment: What is a linking command? I've got a makefile and have this problem, but don't know where to put -stdlib=libstdc++

Comment: In your Makefile, there should be a "linker rule" to create the binary executable from the intermediate sources (*.o). If your Makefile is standard, then you should introduce this into the LDFLAGS variable.

Comment: How to do it if i use a `cgo` in `golang`.

Answer (score 0):

Those suggestions did not work for me with Mac El capitan. If you have similar issues after upgrading to El Capitan, just run

```
xcode-select --install
```

before trying to compile

Comment: This did not work for me.  Can you help me understand what the purpose of this is?  Maybe I can find out why it doesn't work for me if I know what this is supposed to change/solve.