# ACE fails at Linker in MAC OS X 10.9 (and higher)

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang++, ace

I am trying to compile and run the following simple code in MAC OS X 10.9 with CLANG++:

```
#include "ACE_wrappers/ace/MEM_Stream.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        ACE_MEM_Stream m(3);
        m.close_reader();
        return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
QAs-MacBook:aceTestLinking Moamen$ clang++ myTest.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ace_os_main_i(int, char**)", referenced from:
       _main in moamen-511a28.o
  "ACE_SOCK::ACE_SOCK()", referenced from:
       ACE_MEM_IO::ACE_MEM_IO() in moamen-511a28.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The compile line:

```
clang++ myTest.cpp
```

The CLANG Compiler version I am using:

```
QAs-MacBook:aceTestLinking Moamen$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Notice - I have also tried to compile with "-std=c++11", "-stdlib=libstdc++", as in the following topic:
[C++ linking error after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 / Xcode 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637164/c-linking-error-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-xcode-5-0-1)
  but did not solve the issue.

Thanks,

Moamen

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Apparently you aren't linking with ACE library.

Comment: Notice same code worked before in older OS X (10.8 and below), but after CLANG compiler update, it's not working (before I used g++, not clang++).

Comment: I have tried to run **clang++ myTest.cpp -I ACE_wrappers/lib** still getting the same error

Comment: `-l` and `-L` are different compiler options, I believe you have to specify them both with correct values.

Comment: You have to link the ACE library with -lACE, else it will not work. See how we compile and link one of the ACE unit tests

Comment: Thanks for the replies, after some investigation on Linux Ubuntu, I succeeded to compile the code with the following command **g++ -o m.out myTest.cpp ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.a  -I ACE_wrappers/ -lpthread -ldl**. Seems some default libs were missing!

Comment: For MAC OS X - it was my mistake, I needed to include correctly some libs / header files, i.e. **clang++ myTest.cpp ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.a -I ACE_wrappers/**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, after some investigation on Linux Ubuntu, I succeeded to compile the code with the following command g++ -o m.out myTest.cpp ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.a -I ACE_wrappers/ -lpthread -ldl. Seems some default libs were missing!